# Passing Seq[String] to superclass

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a class that must be initilised in the following form:

```
val box = new Box("foo", "bar", "tut")
```

And this is the class that defines it:

```
class Box(boxMembers: String*) {
    val members = boxMembers
}
```

If I want to extend the base class to have named arguments, like this:

```
class FlexibleBox(big: String, small: String, otherMembers: String*) 
    extends Box(big + small + otherMembers) {} //pseudo code
```

How can I pass the 3 arguments (big, small and the other familyMembers) to its superconstructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to m-z's answer, but without the conversion to `List`:

```
class FlexibleBox(big: String, small: String, otherMembers: String*)
    extends Box(big +: small +: otherMembers : _*) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add `big` and `small` to the collection of `otherMembers`, and then use the var-args apply syntax to pass them to the constructor of `Box`:

```
class FlexibleBox(big: String, small: String, otherMembers: String*) 
    extends Box((big :: small :: otherMembers.toList): _ *)

scala> new FlexibleBox("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
res0: FlexibleBox = FlexibleBox@478ee483
```